# TextPosition/PositionWrapper Issues Migrating to PDFBox 2.0.x

Tags: pdfbox

Our department has inherited code that uses Apache PDFBox 1.8.x or earlier and we are in the process of trying to migrate it to Apache PDFBox 2.0.x. I have versions of the last three major versions (1.7.x, 1.8.x, and 2.0.x) that I've looked to for guidance as well as the [Migration to PDFBox 2.0.0](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html) and the [PDFBox Jira Board](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX/).

I have resolved a lot of the various issues in this migration, but I'm still having problems migrating some of the TextPosition related code. The project originally forked the TextPosition code and created setters/getters for all the internal TextPosition fields. I realize this breaks the contract of TextPosition (like Java String) being immutable, so I've pulled all that out. We still have some code that relies on the endX/endY fields, but there are no native getters for these fields and they are marked as private, so a subclass can't even access these fields. **Are there any recommendations on how to access the endX/endY values?**

Also, related to TextPostion, it looks like the PostionWrapper class was dropped on 2.0.x, but I can't find any reference to a replacement for it. **What should we use in place of PositionWrapper?**

Comment: PositionWrapper still exists as a private class in PDFTextStripper.

Comment: Re endX and endY getters, create an enhancement request in JIRA and make an argument why you need them.

Comment: re: PositionWrapper - Thanks. I looked in the Javadocs and couldn't find it. We have a class that extends PDFStreamEngine that is modeled after PDFTextStripper and uses PositionWrapper. I have to see if I can change our code to extend PDFTextStripper or just duplicate the PositionWrapper code for the short term.

Comment: re: endX and endY - I understand the need for TextPosition to be immutable, but we have some code that tries to "fix" spacing issues in the PDF file so that it translates correctly in our conversion. To that end, we have code that swaps characters or adds space between overlapping characters. To accomplish this, we need access to these fields in order to compare X/Y values. We also need these to create copies of the TextPosition fields with values modified slightly. **Do you  think that's a strong enough argument for the change?**

Comment: Yeah, I think so. But it's not just me that you must persuade :-)

Comment: I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3576 to address this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by @Tilman adding getters for `endX` and `endY` (and for some more values) to PDFBox; for details see the PDFBox issue [PDFBOX-3576](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3576) created by the OP. The new getters are available from PDFBox version 2.0.5 onwards.

An alternative for the OP would have been to access the members via reflection. But reflection might not be allowed in all contexts, and members which are now part of the public API are less likely to break over time.